# MVC5: Where could I get System.Web.Mvc.pdb?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I want to debug into MVC5, but I meet the error below:
[image]
Where could I get System.Web.Mvc.pdb file? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dotPeek (free .NET decompiler with debugging functionality, by JetBrains). https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

For other .NET assemblies you could also, in your VS, go to Tools, Options, Debugging, General and select the options "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" and "Enable source server support", which will download symbols for some .NET assemblies. It will not download symbols for the MVC assembly though as it is not considered part of the basic framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ ?
You should be able to download the source and build with debug mode to get the PDB.